# CSS - how to adjust container width to paragraph length, preventing it from wrapping?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm certain that my question is googleable, but I can't find the answer.

I want to archieve effect like in many SMS android apps, where bubbles have a width of paragraph width + paddings. I hope I'm understandable :)

live example:

https://codepen.io/crova/pen/gzNzqG

html:

```
<div class="message">

  <img class="author-photo" src="http://institutogoldenprana.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/no-avatar-25359d55aa3c93ab3466622fd2ce712d1.jpg">

  <div class="message-main">
    <p class="message-info">John Smith, 15:14</p>

    <div class="bubble">
      <p class="message-content">
        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

scss:

```
.message {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  min-height: min-content;
}

.author-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.message-main {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.bubble {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  text-align: left;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(-1rem);
  }
}

.message-content {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<div class="message">

  <img class="author-photo" src="http://institutogoldenprana.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/no-avatar-25359d55aa3c93ab3466622fd2ce712d1.jpg">

  <div class="message-main">
    <p class="message-info">John Smith, 15:14</p>

    <div class="bubble">
      <p class="message-content">
        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.message {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  min-height: min-content;
}

.author-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.message-main {
  /*
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  max-width: 500px; /* Change to any max value you need */
}

.bubble {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  text-align: left;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(-1rem);
  }
}

.message-content {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">

  <img class="author-photo" src="http://institutogoldenprana.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/no-avatar-25359d55aa3c93ab3466622fd2ce712d1.jpg">

  <div class="message-main">
    <p class="message-info">John Smith, 15:14</p>

    <div class="bubble">
      <p class="message-content">
        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change you have to do is remove "width:100%" from the "message-main" class

```css
.message {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  min-height: min-content;
}

.author-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.message-main {
  //width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.bubble {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  text-align: left;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(-1rem);
  }
}

.message-content {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">

  <img class="author-photo" src="http://institutogoldenprana.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/no-avatar-25359d55aa3c93ab3466622fd2ce712d1.jpg">

  <div class="message-main">
    <p class="message-info">John Smith, 15:14</p>

    <div class="bubble">
      <p class="message-content">
        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your code updated .

[Updated working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjozjd)``

You have to set in class bubble `width: max-content;` and in bubble:before `display: inline-block;`